# Extend UIView to automatically add a label (or perform another init action)

Tags: ios, swift

Recently at work, I've been tasked with putting together an app that creates all of its views programmatically rather than via a storyboard. For the most part this worked well, aside from more back-and-forth between running the app and tweaking the views. As a fun side project I wanted to build a "debug" kit to assist those who're in the same boat.

What has really helped me with alignment/styling is a 3rd party library for css-like styling (http://classy.as), which allows me to see the boundaries of each layer/view after adding the following snippet to the stylesheet:

```
^UIView {
    layer: @{
        borderWidth: 1;
    }
}
```

I'd want something similar, but with a label attached to the top-left corner naming the component's class name. Effectively, what I'd want is an auto-generated and auto-attached label on each UIView, preferably one that can be toggled via a variable (i.e. `debugLabel`). I tried to achieve that via the following code:

```
private var debugLabelsEnabled: Bool = false
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var debugLabel: Bool! {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &debugLabelsEnabled) as? Bool
        }
        set(value) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &debugLabelsEnabled, value, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN))
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: self.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 15)))
            label.text = _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(self)
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 9)
            self.addSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

I then tried to test the above snippet via Classy, by setting `debugLabel` on `^UIView` as well. That had no effect. However, individually setting `myView.debugLabel = true` does work. Unfortunately, I can't expect the developer to manually set this property on each view. I want something along the lines of Classy's logic, where I could toggle that label for all of the elements in view (and those that may appear later).

**What I'm basically trying to do is modify the initialization logic for all UIViews to do something extra without having to subclass (because I want all existing elements inheriting from UIView to automatically execute this logic).** Could someone help me out? Is there a sane way to achieve that? One way I was thinking of going up to root view controller and then recursively iterating through all of its subviews, but that won't handle views that are not currently shown, like Classy does. I don't mind switching to Obj-C for this if needed, I would, however, prefer to keep the rest of my logic in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As far as I know there are only 2 useful init of UIView so you can easily achieve what you want by using `convenience` init.</strike>

```
class FancyView : UIView {
    var foo = 0
}

extension UIView {
    convenience init(frame : CGRect?, addDebugThings: Bool) {

    if frame != nil {
        self.init(frame: frame!)
    } else {
        self.init()
    }

    if addDebugThings {
        addLabel()
    }

}

private func addLabel() {
    println("add label")
}
}

let view = UIView(frame: nil, addDebugThings: true)
let fancy = FancyView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 35.0, 350.0, 350.0), addDebugThings: false)
```

**Edit:**
As of you pointed me that it wont work with UIView subclasses the other method I can suggest is method swizzling, but that'd require to migrate to Obj-C, unfortunately.

This is an example of how one can easily do it.

**UIView+Border.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface UIView(Border)
@end
```

**UIView+Border.m:**

```
#import "UIView+Border.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView(Border)

- (id)swizzled_initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    // You might think it is an endless recursion but it is not.
    id result = [self swizzled_initWithFrame:frame];

    // Safe guard: do we have an UIView (or something that has a layer)?
    if ([result respondsToSelector:@selector(layer)]) {
        // Get layer for this view.
        CALayer *layer = [result layer];
        // Set border on layer.
        layer.borderWidth = 2;
        layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    }

    // Return the modified view.
    return result;
}

- (id)swizzled_initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    // You might think it is an endless recursion but it is not.
    id result = [self swizzled_initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    // Safe guard: do we have an UIView (or something that has a layer)?
    if ([result respondsToSelector:@selector(layer)]) {
        // Get layer for this view.
        CALayer *layer = [result layer];
        // Set border on layer.
        layer.borderWidth = 2;
        layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    }

    // Return the modified view.
    return result;
}

+ (void)load
{
    // The "+ load" method is called once, very early in the application life-cycle.
    // It's called even before the "main" function is called. Beware: there's no
    // autorelease pool at this point, so avoid Objective-C calls.
    Method original, swizzle;

    // Get the "- (id)initWithFrame:" method.
    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(initWithFrame:));
    // Get the "- (id)swizzled_initWithFrame:" method.
    swizzle = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzled_initWithFrame:));
    // Swap their implementations.
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzle);

    // Get the "- (id)initWithCoder:" method.
    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(initWithCoder:));
    // Get the "- (id)swizzled_initWithCoder:" method.
    swizzle = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzled_initWithCoder:));
    // Swap their implementations.
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzle);
}

@end
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't force everything else that uses or inherits from UIView (UITextField, UILabel, UITableView, UITableCell, etc.) to trigger the correct init in their logic.

Comment: Oh I thought you were talking about your own subclasses.

Comment: Well, now I provided another solution, that really should work for you.